# Align ScrollView above but keep using as much height as needed

Tags: android

I'd like to use a `RadioGroup` with `RadioButton` in a `Dialog`. I can have few `RadioButton` & I can have a lot of them, that's why I wrapped `RadioGroup` in a `ScrollView`. My layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title_settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title_settings">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_options_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For the case with a lot of views I get:
[image]

The problem is with few elements:
[image]

I want it to ignore this empty space. I was trying with `LinearLayout` but the items overlap my button. Is there a workaround for this?

P.S. I can put `RadioButton` elements in a `RecycleView` but I have to restart it every time user selects a new `RadioButton` to achieve `RadioGroup` property - so I refused this idea.

Comment: use fillViewPort property true in scrollview

Comment: Add this property `android:fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView

Comment: are you using `DialogInterface.OnShowListener` ?

Comment: the problem is that i'm using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for my button, that's why I get full height if i delete this the scroll view will overlap the button in case there are a lot of options.